# SpagoBI: create a dynamic chart using SpagoBI

Tags: charts, highcharts, fiware, spagobi

I am starting with SpagoBI, I managed to display a static chart using Highchart, what I want to do is a dynamic chart means if my data set is updated I want my chart to be updated as well, without manually refreshing the web page. like the example under this link [1]
I used SpagoBi studio to deploy the chart, I tested the option of "refresh Seconds" (I edited to 1 second) while deploying but it is not working.

How can I do that?

Update: the chart template:

```
<HIGHCHART width="100%" height="100%">
  <CHART defaultSeriesType="spline" zoomType="xy"/>
  <TITLE text="Temperature 1"/>
  <LEGEND/>
  <SUBTITLE/>
  <X_AXIS allowDecimals="true" maxZoom="4" min="0" tickWidth="1" type="linear" alias="recvTime">
    <TITLE/>
  </X_AXIS>
  <Y_AXIS maxPadding="0.0" maxZoom="4" tickWidth="1" type="linear" alias="attrValue">
    <TITLE/>
  </Y_AXIS>
  <PLOT_OPTIONS>
    <SPLINE stacking="">
      <DATA_LABELS/>
    </SPLINE>
  </PLOT_OPTIONS>
  <DRILL>
    <PARAM_LIST/>
  </DRILL>
  <SERIES_LIST>
    <SERIES name="Temperature" alias="recvTime,attrValue" type="spline"/>
  </SERIES_LIST>
</HIGHCHART>
```

[1]http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: 1) You can use ajax in javascript and call script to get data and check if is modified or not
2) Use socket

Comment: but I want to use SpagoBI :(

Comment: But spangoDB return you a data, so you need to have a script which extract data from there and push into javascript / highcharts. One of way is ajax/socket.

Comment: yes I know that using Ajax and javascript is a way to do it, but I am looking for how to do it using SpagoBI (http://www.spagobi.org/)

Comment: So at the beginning check if possible to get data from spagoBI to javascript directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the refresh_time property:

<HIGHCHART refresh_time='5' width="100%" height="100%" >
....

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem with the "Refresh seconds" option... are you using the FIWARE package or another SpagoBI version?
Anyway, using the "Refresh seconds" option, the chart will be re-created from scratch at the specified rate, not updated as the Highchart example.
Charts provided by SpagoBI with the ExtJS library can be refreshed: just specify "refreshTime" in the template XML root tag:

```
<EXTCHART refreshTime='10'...
```

this will let the chart refresh its data without being re-created from scratch.
But, refreshing data is still not exactly the "time shifting" functionality as in the Highcharts example; if you are looking for that, you should have a look at the Console[1] engine.

Best regards

Davide

[1] http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/Console

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I am not using FIWARE package I used the following package: "All-In-One-SpagoBI-5.1-21012015.zip", I edited my answer with my chart template, I am using highchart not EXTCHART, is the refresh possible with this type of charts? Thanks.