# How can I see real time modifications of my data using a Fiware Enabler?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am looking for a Fiware generic enabler that I can use to see my data modifications in real time, for example a chart like this [1] for my temperature sensor data. My data are stored in a MongoDB data base.

I am wondering if I can use "FIWARE Wirecloud" to visualize my data in real time. if no, is there another fiware enabler that I can use?

[1] http://www.highcharts.com/stock/dynamic-update

Answer (score 2):

Definetively, you can achieve what you want with Wirecloud. You will also need Orion Context broker (another enabler), which is the key here to "visualize my data in real time".

You would like to have a look into this [demo](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/live-demo-macs), where you will find a similar example where entity "buses" are tracked by their geoposition in real time.

I leave you here some useful link you may need:

1- [Orion - Github](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-browser-widget)

2.-[Wirecloud - Github](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud)

3.- [Wirecloud Course](http://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=53)

¡Happy Coding!

Comment: I think that the demo link is not pointing into the correct URL, would be great if you fix it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it with Wirecloud, I hope somebody gives you the answer.

But you could check SpagoBI as alternative if there is no way to do it with Wirecloud.

http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/data-visualization-spagobi

http://www.spagobi.org/

Comment: I have checked spagoBI and I found it more adapted to give a static analysis, I got some real time graphics using its consol but I did not found it that advanced, couldn't found how to do such charts with it, I have already post a thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985057/spagobi-create-a-dynamic-chart-using-spagobi) about that, I got no response :(